# How to get the classes to be called by other addons?

Tags: python, add-on

if I want these classes to be called by other plugins, like Pie Menu Editor addon, What code should I add？

[image]

```
import bpy

class Cam_Base(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "cam.base"
    bl_label = "Cam Base"
    cam_name = "C_"
    
    def execute(self, context):
        C = bpy.context

        # lock cam
        bpy.context.object.lock_scale = (True, True, True)
        bpy.context.object.lock_rotation = (True, True, True)
        bpy.context.object.lock_location = (True, True, True)

        # select cam
        bpy.context.space_data.camera = bpy.data.objects[self.cam_name]

        # Select Active Cam
        for area in C.screen.areas:
            if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                A = C.area.spaces.active.camera

        bpy.context.scene.camera = bpy.data.objects[A.name]

        bpy.context.space_data.shading.color_type = 'OBJECT'
        bpy.context.space_data.region_3d.view_perspective = 'CAMERA'
#############Supplementary Code################
        #Modify camera attributes
        bpy.data.objects[A.name].lock_scale[0] = True
        bpy.data.objects[A.name].lock_scale[1] = True
        bpy.data.objects[A.name].lock_scale[2] = True
        bpy.data.objects[A.name].lock_location[0] = True
        bpy.data.objects[A.name].lock_location[1] = True
        bpy.data.objects[A.name].lock_location[2] = True
        bpy.data.objects[A.name].lock_rotation[0] = True
        bpy.data.objects[A.name].lock_rotation[1] = True
        bpy.data.objects[A.name].lock_rotation[2] = True
        bpy.data.objects[A.name].scale[0] = 1
        bpy.data.objects[A.name].scale[1] = 1
        bpy.data.objects[A.name].scale[2] = 1
        bpy.data.cameras[A.name].display_size = 0.05
        bpy.data.cameras[A.name].background_images[0].alpha = 0
        bpy.data.cameras[A.name].dof.use_dof = False
        bpy.data.cameras[A.name].clip_start = 25
        bpy.data.cameras[A.name].clip_end = 100000
        bpy.data.cameras[A.name].background_images[0].scale = 1
        bpy.data.cameras[A.name].background_images[1].scale = 1
        bpy.data.cameras[A.name].background_images[2].scale = 1

        bpy.ops.view3d.view_center_camera()
        bpy.ops.image.reload()
    
        #select camera as active objcet in object mode
        if bpy.context.object.mode == 'OBJECT':
            bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
            objectToSelect = bpy.data.objects[A.name]
            objectToSelect.select_set(True)
            bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = objectToSelect
#############Supplementary Code################
        return {'FINISHED'}

class Cam_0V0(Cam_Base):
    bl_idname = "cam.0v0"
    bl_label = "Cam_0V0"
    cam_name = "C_0V0"

class Cam_0V1(Cam_Base):
    bl_idname = "cam.0v1"
    bl_label = "Cam_0V1"
    cam_name = "C_0V1"

class Cam_0V2(Cam_Base):
    bl_idname = "cam.0v2"
    bl_label = "Cam_0V2"
    cam_name = "C_0V2"

addon_keymaps = []

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(Cam_Base)
    bpy.utils.register_class(Cam_0V0)
    bpy.utils.register_class(Cam_0V1)
    bpy.utils.register_class(Cam_0V2)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Cam_Base)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Cam_0V0)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Cam_0V1)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Cam_0V2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: AFAIK it won't work if you use inheritance in that way. An operator class must inherit *directly* from `bpy.types.Operator` to correctly register. It's a quirk of the API. You can use composition though, and inherit from `Operator` *and* another class

Comment: So how do I change the code?

Comment: make `Cam_Base` a base class (no inheritance) and define your child classes with `Cam_0V0(Cam_Base, bpy.types.Operator):`. Note that you won't be able to register `Cam_Base`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [context overrides](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add). In this example, I added your operator buttons into the header of the [`Python Console`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/python_console.html):

```
import bpy

class Cam_Base():
    bl_idname = "cam.base"
    bl_label = "Cam Base"
    cam_name = "C_"

    def execute(self, context):
        area_type = 'VIEW_3D'
        areas = [area for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas if area.type == area_type]

        if len(areas) <= 0:
            raise Exception(f"Make sure an Area of type {area_type} is open or visible in your screen!")

        with bpy.context.temp_override(area=areas[0]):        
            c = bpy.context
            c.object.lock_scale = (True, True, True)
            c.object.lock_rotation = (True, True, True)
            c.object.lock_location = (True, True, True)
            c.space_data.camera = bpy.data.objects[self.cam_name]
            c.scene.camera = bpy.data.objects[self.cam_name]

        return {'FINISHED'}


class Cam_0V0(bpy.types.Operator, Cam_Base):
    bl_idname = "cam.cam0"
    bl_label = "Cam_0V0"
    cam_name = "C_0V0"


class Cam_0V1(bpy.types.Operator, Cam_Base):
    bl_idname = "cam.cam1"
    bl_label = "Cam_0V1"
    cam_name = "C_0V1"


class Cam_0V2(bpy.types.Operator, Cam_Base):
    bl_idname = "cam.cam2"
    bl_label = "Cam_0V2"
    cam_name = "C_0V2"


class Info_Head(bpy.types.Header):
    bl_space_type = 'INFO'

    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.operator("cam.cam0")
        self.layout.operator("cam.cam1")
        self.layout.operator("cam.cam2")

    bpy.types.CONSOLE_HT_header.prepend(draw)


addon_keymaps = []

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(Cam_0V0)
    bpy.utils.register_class(Cam_0V1)
    bpy.utils.register_class(Cam_0V2)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Cam_0V0)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Cam_0V1)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Cam_0V2)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: You are wonderful! But I missed a piece of code before, how to add this piece of code to the new code, can you help me to simplify and standardize this code, the new code is in between #Supplementary Code# and #Supplementary Code#  I tried it myself to add but it reported an error, so I'll have to ask you

Comment: ah just nest the supplementary code after `with bpy.context.temp_override` similar to my answer

Comment: All other code is normal, but this is the only one that reports an error ”bpy.ops.view3d.view_center_camera()”     ----RuntimeError:Operator bpy.ops.view3d.view center camera.poll（）failed,context is incorrect .  How do I go about modifying it?

Comment: `bpy.ops.view3d.view_center_camera()` should also work within the VIEW_3D context. can u edit your question and add an updated version of your code

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but there was an error. Here is the full code of the error. 
Python:Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\blues\AppData\RoamingBlender Foundation\Blender3.3\scripts\addons\CamS3.py",line 49,in execute
bpy.ops.view3d.view_center_camera（）
File "C:\Programs\blender-3.3.0-windows-x6413.3\scripts\modules\bpyops.py".line 113,in call
ret op call(self.idname_py（）,None,kw)
RuntimeError:Operator bpy.ops.view3d.view_center_camera.poll（）failed,context is incorrect

Comment: Just this line, correct the code， it would to be perfection, I will rename  author of this plugin by you name

Comment: yeah i tried as well, i could not figure it out. i will try again tomorrow https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95793/how-to-use-view-center-camera-for-fitting-camera-to-3d-view

Comment: hi，You rewrite the code there is a little problem, before my code ca switch the area‘s camera in the current area where the mouse is located,it is this paragraph code： “bpy.context.space_data.camera = bpy.data.objects["C_0V0"]” change to “c.space_data.camera = bpy.data.objects[self.cam_name]” It doesn't work anymore.，But the new code can only switch the camera in one area now when there ara many areas in windows, how can I modify it? –